# Array list of image url from server to a tableview xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

i try to show image in my tableview from my array list of image url (my server)
i would like to show the number of cell for each of my image in my array list
i call a request

```
#import "ProfileViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "Recipe.h"


@interface ProfileViewController ()



@end

@implementation ProfileViewController {
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBarImage.png"]];
UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackGround.png"]];
self.view.backgroundColor = background;

_showBtn.target = self.revealViewController;
_showBtn.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];


CFStringRef tokenK = CFSTR("token");
CFStringRef token;

// Read the preference.
token = (CFStringRef)CFPreferencesCopyAppValue(tokenK,
                                               kCFPreferencesCurrentApplication);
// When finished with value, you must release it
CFRelease(token);

NSLog(@"Token: %@",token);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.egip.it/luca/imglist.php"]];

NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"token=%@",token];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:returnData];
UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
imageView.image = image;

NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"returnString: %@",returnString);








 ;

}




  @end
```

in my log i see the string of the url's image but i I would like to put on the tableview this image but i don't know how doing this

thanks for the answer and i apologize for my english !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIImage image = [UIImage imageWithData:returnData];
UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
imageView.image = image;
```

After having the `UIImageView` setup correctly as shown above, you will add it as the subview of whatever view you want to see it in:

```
[tableViewCell addSubview:imageView];
```

However, getting the image for a `UITableViewCell` from the server synchronously is NOT a good idea. It will slow down the `UITableView` scrolling like crazy.

Comment: where i put this ? in viewdidload?

Comment: there is a error in initWithFrame:frame . it told me that "use  of undeclared indentifier 'frame1

Comment: Try with new code and say if you see an image, i edited the answer

Comment: You put those 4 lines below `NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];`

Comment: but in self.yourtableview whats i will put in?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just display the image using the AFNetworking function setImageWithURL, it takes the URL of an image and sets the UIImageView to that image. Its a much simpler way of doing things if you only need to display it.

It looks something like this:

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
```

In the header file you'll have something like this:

```
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

Its much faster as well.

Here's a link: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: i would put many image from the server and i would to display all of my image

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand..?

Comment: i have more image not only one and i would put the image from my server in the tableview (like instagramm)

Comment: Yes, when you do the request to get all the images, you will get an array of URL's. Once you have the array of URL's you will use AFNetworking to display the images.

Comment: it give me this 3 error                                      Diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
Diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.